# Problem with JS function in TS file with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am building simple sharepoint webpart and i have a problem with using a function in my main file from other module file.

Part of the file JSFunctions.module.js (file where i create my function):

```
function getApi(){
  [my code]...
  };
  export { getApi }
```

Part of the file TestWebpartWebPart.ts (main file with body of my webpart):

```
import { getApi } from './JSFunctions.module.js';

this.domElement.innerHTML = `
<input type="text" id="userEmailInput"><br><br>
<input type="Button" Value="Przycisk" onClick=${getApi()}><br><br>
<div id="html_BirthdayTable"></div>
  `;
```

Everythng is fine with html code, but i have problem wih onClick=${getApi()}.

When i type onClick${getApi()} there is error on the page: "Object(...) os not a function"

When i type onClick${getApi} there is no error on the page but after clicking on the button nothing happens and when i inspect the code on the page o can see onclick="undefined"

The same happens when I tried "export function getApi(){}" in the JSFunctions.module.js file

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `getApi` returns `"some_result"` for the sake of simplicity. Your html will compile to `onClick=some_result`. That's not valid html and that won't work as you expect.

What you're trying to do is call `getApi` on button click. That would better be achieved with something along the lines of

```js
// define getApi in the global scope so it can be referrenced in the DOM
window.getApi = getAPi;
// reference it in the dom
this.domElement.innetHTML = `...<input onclick="getApi">...`
```

Comment: my `getApi` function is returning data by `document.getElementById('html_BirthdayTable').innerHTML = html_BirthdayTable`

Comment: In your method i dont understand where i should put `window.getApi = getApi`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an inline `onclick` attribute. Attach an event listener to the button.

```
this.domElement.innerHTML = `
    <input type="text" id="userEmailInput"><br><br>
    <input type="Button" value="Przycisk"><br><br>
    <div id="html_BirthdayTable"></div>
`;

document.querySelector('button[value="Przycisk"]').addEventListener("click", getApi);
```

Comment: So where i need to put `document.querySelector('button[value="Przycisk"]').addEventListener("click", getApi)`?
It look like it should be inside JSFunctions.module.js file but how can i link this two files.
I know in normal html site i can type `<script scr="file.js"></script>` but i don't know where to palce it in sharepoint webpart project

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about Sharepoint. Just copy/paste this code. It creates the button in HTML, and then attaches an event listener to it

Comment: Thanks for help :) It finally works for me, my problem with your solution was accidentaly putting `document.querySelector...` before `this.domElement.innerHTML` so this was not working for first try and for now i put my function inside file with my html code

Comment: Nice, if my solution worked, please don't forget to mark it as accepted :)